# How can a sensor apply a voltage?

Tags: voltage, sensor

[image: TMP36]

*(from http://www.adafruit.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/tmp36pinout.jpg)*

Have a look at this picture. It's a simple heat sensor. Though it looks like it's really simple, I don't fully understand how the middle pin works.

How can a voltage be applied? I thought it was merely an abstract concept for the difference in potential electrical energy.

And how does it work for this heat sensor in particular?

Comment: Bad link to picture.  Tried to fix, and get "forbidden" on provided link

Comment: Oh that's weird. I'll have a look at it too.

Comment: Should be fixed now :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [link](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/TMP35_36_37.pdf) to the spec sheet.   I'd call it a temperature sensor.  (heat has units of energy.)  You have to apply power so the internal circuitry provides an output voltage.

It looks to be a silicon band gap temp sensor described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_bandgap_temperature_sensor)

Answer (score 2):

*How can a voltage be applied? I thought it was merely an abstract concept for the difference in potential electrical energy.*

Your thinking has gone wrong here, somewhere around "abstract concept". "Potential", "electrical", and indeed "energy" are all abstractions. We reason with abstractions because they are much easier to reason with than trying to re-derive everything from first principles or observations every time. Voltage is a measurable property of electric fields.

I can't work out what you mean by "apply current instead of voltage", especially since you seem to think that current isn't an abstract concept in the same way that voltage is. Generally by "apply a voltage" we mean "connect to some voltage source".

Comment: Here's how I see it: Current is a stream of electrons, and voltage is the potential 'amount of electrons'. The voltage is similar to a magnet in a magnetic field. This is probably wrong then?

Comment: Quite similar (electric field rather than magnetic). One coulomb of electrons moving along a one Volt potential gradient carries one Joule of energy. Whereas one coulomb of electrons moving past a particular point constitutes a current of one Amp.

Comment: @PenguinCake, voltage is the difference in electric potential, not the difference in electric potential energy.  Electric potential is the potential energy per unit charge.  So voltage tells us potential "per unit" and doesn't tell us the "amount of electrons."  You could think of gravitational potential (GP) and gravitational potential energy (GPE).  GPE depends on both the height and mass of an object.  GP (analogous to voltage) is more like talking about the GPE per kilogram.  GP would give you a mass-independent way to talk about gravity.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/TMP35_36_37.pdf  -- see page 8.

The simple sensor actually has about 10 transistors on it, carefully constructed so that the VBE (a transistor parameter) of two of the transistors differ in a way that is largely dependent on temperature.  The difference causes some current across some resistors.

Comment: So does it in reality apply current instead of voltage?

Comment: No, there's some transistor circuitry to generate a voltage output that can provide enough current to feed any next stage (withing reason).  "Apply" isn't quite accurate, or at least uncommon in this context.  I doesn't "apply" so much as "generate".

Comment: It really delivers a voltage, and you can place a very small load on it and draw a tiny amount of current without making the measurement inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a fundamental mis-understanding.  The principle in electronics is that you have a signal that is representative of a real world signal.  The term Analog electronics really comes from "analogous" or similar to.  Instead of trying to build light and sound amplifiers you move the signal to the electrical domain, operate on it and then perhaps move it back.  This movement back and forth is accomplished through transducers which usually require power to operate.

In this device there is circuitry that converts the temperature of it's substrate to an electrical signal.

Answer (score 0):

The sensor really does supply a voltage.  It uses a couple of internal transistors to build a temperature sensitive voltage divider.  It then uses some more transistors to provide that voltage through a buffer amplifier.  The upshot of all this is that it provides a voltage proportional to the temperature, and you can draw up to 250µA of current when measuring the voltage.

It actually works based on the fact that the gain of a transistor is in part dependent on the temperature.  If you set your bias and base resistors to provide a certain current through the transistor, the actual current will depend on the junction temperature of the transistor.  Current flowing through a resistor results in a voltage drop across the resistor.  In this sensor, the two transistors play the part of of the resistor - measuring the voltage drop is an indirect measure of the current.

Comment: More accurately, its designed such that the VBE of the two transistors differ, not necessarily the gain.